# JavaFX BorderPane inside ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm currently trying to build an app with JavaFX and the SceneBuilder and I got to a point where I need to ask you guys for some help:

I have a BorderPane inside a ScrollPane. The BorderPane is fed with elements so that it grows horizontaly in size. I put the BorderPane inside a ScrollPane so that it automatically adds scrollbars when it reaches the ScrollPane's limits and I can simply scroll to see the stuff further to the right.

When using an AnchorPane inside a ScrollPane it works like a charm. When more space is used than the size of the Window(the ScrollPane), it automatically adds the scrollbars.

But I can't seem to make this work with a BorderPane inside a ScrollPane. If I resize the Windows manualy it shows all the elements, though...

The fxml-part looks like this:

```html
<ScrollPane hbarPolicy="AS_NEEDED" pannable="false" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" vbarPolicy="AS_NEEDED"   AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="200.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
  <content>
    <BorderPane fx:id="contentPane" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" />
  </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Does anyone know why it's not working with a BorderPane?

Comment: Try to put BorderPane inside AnchorPane inside ScrollPane perhaps?

Comment: The code you posted (or the equivalent Java code) work just fine for me. The problem is probably elsewhere in your layout. You need to expand this to a [MCVE] to get help with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I used the BorderPane the wrong way. I tried pulling ScrollPanes inside the different regions of the BorderPane and everything works like I wanted it to. Thanks anyways!